# Built-in Windows VPN PPTP not working for user

Tags: vpn

I am trying to setup a built in Windows VPN PPTP for a client on their laptop, and when it tries to connect to their VPN server it fails with VPN error 806.

I've enabled GRE protocol and opened TCP port 1723 but the error still persists.

Is there a small detail that I could be missing? I've copied the exact same setup from another user who has it working.

Comment: How are you measuring if the connection is making it to the VPN server?

Answer (score 0):

Error 806 is (mostly) a packet flow error in GRE. Make sure tcp port 1723 and tcp protocol type 47 (not port 46) are reachable. Also check that on the clientside, it has to be behind a router/nat/firewall that allows GRE, too.

Many "free wifi" hotel accesspoints, ISPs using CGN, 'tunneled' connections (like nordvpn) drop GRE in the first place.